# IOS 8 xCode 6 button appears disabled but is not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Environment: IOS 8.02 Xcode 6

I have a form on a StoryBoard. It has 2 labels a text box and 2 buttons.
btnValidateAndSave disables all of the other controls on the form and calls a web service.

btnCance goes grey as if it has been disabled however it is clickable.

Below is the actual code behind the form.

```
#import "vcDigitalKeyManager.h"
#import "serviceManager.h"
#import "eziEnums.h"
#import "IsSystemLockedMethod.h"
#import "eziResponse.h"

@interface vcDigitalKeyManager ()
- (IBAction)btnValidateAndSave:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtDigitalKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblErrorMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *lblValidateActivity;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnValidateAndSave;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCancel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *isWorking;

- (IBAction)btnCancel:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation vcDigitalKeyManager

@synthesize txtDigitalKey = _txtDigitalKey;
@synthesize lblErrorMessage = _lblErrorMessage;
@synthesize btnCancel = _btnCancel;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.lblValidateActivity setHidden:true];

}

- (IBAction)btnValidateAndSave:(id)sender {

    [self.txtDigitalKey resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtDigitalKey setEnabled:NO];
    [self.txtDigitalKey setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [self.lblValidateActivity setHidden:NO];

    [self.btnValidateAndSave setEnabled:NO];
    [self.btnValidateAndSave setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [self.txtDigitalKey setEnabled:NO];
    [self.txtDigitalKey setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    self.btnCancel.enabled=NO;
    self.btnCancel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [self.lblValidateActivity startAnimating];

    _isWorking = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    NSString * requestBody = [serviceManager buildSoapMessage:IsSystemLocked :self.txtDigitalKey.text ];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(displayEziResponse:)
                                                 name:@"kIsSystemLockedResponseNotification"
                                               object:nil];

     [[[IsSystemLockedMethod alloc]init] callNonPciMethod:requestBody servicetype:NonPci];

}

- (void) displayEziResponse:(NSNotification *) notification{

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    eziResponse *myResponse = [userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"];

    if([myResponse.ErrorNumber isEqual:@"0"])
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.lblErrorMessage setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",myResponse.ErrorNumber, myResponse.ErrorMessage]];
        [self.lblErrorMessage setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.lblErrorMessage setHidden:NO];

        [self.lblValidateActivity stopAnimating];
        [self.lblValidateActivity setHidden:YES];

        [self.btnValidateAndSave setEnabled:YES];
        [self.btnValidateAndSave setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [self.txtDigitalKey setEnabled:YES];
        [self.txtDigitalKey setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [self.btnCancel setEnabled:YES];
        [self.btnCancel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    }



}

- (IBAction)btnCancel:(id)sender {

    //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",NSStringFromBOOL(BOOL self.btnCancel.enabled)]);

    if(_isWorking == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])
    {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    //if(self.btnCancel.enabled)

}
@end
```

I have tested this in the simulator and on an iPhone 5S
Any Ideas how to actually disable the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it was not actually the button that was the issue.

The Validate and Save button calls a function that does an async call to a web service.

I am using notifications to let the main thread know when the response has been received.

The notification was being sent back on the background thread.  The affect of this was that the Cancel button was being enabled in real time but not the visual state.

I modified the code so the notification is sent back to the main thread and now everything updates on the main thread within 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer also disabling user interaction on the button !

```
[self.btnCancel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: I'm sure its wired up otherwise it wouldn't turn grey.

Comment: @WilkieIT ok ! Then try disabling userInteraction on the button like I did above in the answer :) and I updated my answer btw!

Comment: I have updated the description and provided the full code from behind the form.  I have also updated the code to match what you suggested but still no luck.

Comment: I did a test and added a property called IsWorking and I change the value when clicking btnValidateAndSave button.  I check the value when clicking btnCancel and because it doesn't match everything stops. However the button becomes green again.  Could this have anything to do with the fact that it is a modal segue?

Comment: Additionally I have tried using both control messaging and dotNotation and neither option worked.  Its almost like its on a separate thread.

Comment: OK... I have worked out what the issue is I am just unsure how to fix it.  The problem is not the button it the appears to be the refresh of the form.  I added debugging to the response from the notification centre to the SaveAndValidate button is less than a second. But then the form sits there and does not update.